# ActiveRecord search for similar entries to show page selection (Rails 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, controller, rails-activerecord

I have a show page generated from a very large database, queried by `@listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id])` in the controller. At the bottom of the page I also have links to three other listings; for now they are queried by `@listings = Listing.last(3)`, but I am trying to pick three similar listings - by community, or by a price range.

example - `Listing.where(:price => 500000..600000).limit(2)`

However...I am at a loss as to how to do this in comparison to the active page listing. How would I pick listings from the same community, or within a certain price range of the same record, for instance? If someone could direct me as to how to make this connection I would appreciate it (I'm fairly junior, but also am really learning to enjoy ActiveRecord, and want to expand  what I can do with it).

Before anyone asks, here's my schema:

```
 create_table "listings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "mls"
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
    t.string   "community"
    t.string   "description"
    t.integer  "price"
    t.string   "status"
    t.string   "address"
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need something like this:

```
price_range = (@listing.price - 100)..(@listing.price + 100)
Listing.where(price: price_range, community: @listing.community).limit(3)
```

You were on the right track!